Skecher import add-on error
I am trying to import the add-on Sketcher import. On Blender add-ons it is supported on version 4.2 and later, my version is 4.4 gfor ARM architecture and after imported a pop up window appears with a error message.
Any clue about that.
Thank for your time and cooperation
Kind regards

What error message? If you mean the CAD Sketcher addon, it probably links to binary components, and as such is platform dependent. Very likely no one compiled a version specific for ARM devices, especially considering how relatively new support is.

Thanks Duarte. I made mistake the problem is with Sketchup and not with Sketcher. I find more information on https://extensions.blender.org/approval-queue/sketchup-importer/. I will do some tests following some recommendations

It works on X64 architecture
